# Spring autowire stops working for classes on the Tomcat classpath

Tags: spring, tomcat, classpath, autowired, inject

Inside my library `FooLibrary.jar` Spring instantiates class `com.example.FooImpl` which has a property `bars`. I have lots of `Bar` instances also instantiated by Spring. A set of bars is autowired into `FooImpl` like this:

```
@Component
public class FooImpl {
  @Inject
  private Set<Bar> bars;
```

In a standalone application, Spring instantiates the `Bar` instances, instantiates the `FooImpl` instances, and then autowires `FooImpl.bars` with the set of `Bar`s. It works.

Now I'm running the same Spring configuration in a webapp inside Tomcat. `FooLibrary.jar` is inside `WEB-INF/lib`, and everything continues to work as outlined above.

The problem is that the web app automatically compiles somes classes using `JavaCompiler`, [which can't find its dependencies for dynamically compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887057) unless I place that library on the startup Tomcat path. The minute I add `FooLibrary.jar` to the Tomcat classpath (e.g. in in the launch configuration of Tomcat inside Eclipse, or I presume `startup.sh` or `setclasspath.bat` if running Tomcat standalone), autowire stops working.

That is, when my webapp starts up, Spring creates all the `Bar` instances, then instantiates `FooImpl`, but **never autowires** the set of `Bar`s into `FooImpl.bars`. **Any idea why?**

(Does it have something to do with the Spring `ContextLoaderListener` being started from the webapp classloader, but the `FooImpl` and `Bar` instances coming from the Tomcat classloader, I wonder?)

Comment: Is FooLibrary.jar also in WEB-INF/lib when this occurs? Autowiring can also fail due to incompatible types (e.g. classes loaded in multiple classloaders.

Comment: Yes, `FooLibrary` continues to reside in `WEB-INF/lib` as well, and indeed must continue there because, besides its role in creating dynamic classes, it is used by the webapp. Furthermore it is placed automatically by Maven in `WEB-INF/lib` because of the dependencies. Is there any way to ensure autowiring takes place correctly?

Comment: Well since you already place the JAR in tomcat's boot classpath, it must be visible to the webapp as well (without you having to place the JAR in WEB-INF/lib). You can make the dependency provided scoped to not have Maven place it in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @Jukka, it appears you were correct in that having the jar in two places can prevent autowiring from occurring. I've got things to work by removing the jar from `WEB-INF/lib`, and your tip on Maven scope reminded me that I could mark the dependency as `provided`. If you'd like to place your response in an answer I can mark it as the correct response. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: I copy-pasted a summary of my comments as an answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowiring can fail due to incompatible types (e.g. classes loaded in multiple classloaders).

Since you already place the JAR in tomcat's boot classpath, it must be visible to the webapp as well without you having to place the JAR in WEB-INF/lib.

You can make the dependency scope `provided` to not have Maven place it in WEB-INF/lib.